# SQL Server Read Committed Snapshot

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, transactions, isolation-level

I am just wondering something about snapshot behavior on read committed isolation level. Let's assume that I have a table with name "A". Here is the first transaction:

```
Select blabla 
From A

Insert Into A blabla
```

and second transaction does the same

```
Select blabla 
From A

Insert Into A blabla
```

and assume that below timeline occurred:

```
Tran1: select
Tran1: insert (not yet committed)
Tran2: select (I don't know it is possible or not)
Tran2: insert
```

As far as I know, in standard read committed isolation level, tran2 select query would be blocked because of tran1 insert command not yet committed or rolled back. But, while "is_read_committed_snapshot" is enabled, I expect that any of lock won't acquired during insert or update command.

So what will happen to tran2?

I expect that tran2 select query won't see the data that inserted by tran1, because it would be "dirty read". But it wouldn't get block as well.

Because of the tran1 insert query does not acquire any lock, wouldn't this situation be a problem about concurrency of executing these two transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expect that any of lock won't acquired during insert or update
>   command.

That is wrong. Even if you have enabled `RCSI`, writers still block writers, and `X` locks are still acqiured.

What is different between RC and RCSI is **reading** behaviour. 
When working on pessimistic RC, `SELECT` from Tran2 will be blocked on `X` lock held on A, while working on RCSI Tran2's `SELECT` will not be blocked, it will be provided with the last committed version of A, i.e. with the state of A **before** Tran1 has modificated it.

What happend then depends on your table organisation and on what you `INSERT`.

Some examples.

1) table A is a heap, you are doing single insert in both transactions.

In this case your `INSERT` in Tran2 will succeed in any case, *be it the same value that you try to insert in both transactions or not*, because what the server acquires in this case is `IX` on a table (that is compatible with `IX` held by Tran1), `IX` on a page (that is also compatible with `IX` held by Tran1, even if it is the same page), and `X` on RID (while Tran1 has `X` on *another* RID), so there is no conflict.

2) table A is clustered table, you are trying to insert *the same new key* in this table.

In this case your Tran2's `INSERT` will be blocked because of the conflict between two `X` lock on the same key, the first is held by Tran1, the secont is requested by Tran2 and is blocked.

3) table A is clustered table, you are trying to insert *different keys* in this table.

Insert2 will succeed because `X` lock on key requested by Tran2 will be granted as Tran1 holds `IX` on table, `IX` on page, and `X` on `another` key.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you're doing it this way:

```
SELECT id FROM customers

BEGIN TRAN new_tran
UPDATE customers
```

SET ID = '1'
WHERE ID = '01'

IF your query is something like this:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT
GO
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT *
FROM   customers
WHERE id = '01'
```

Result- Even if we have changed the value to 01, we will still see old record in session 2 (2, TWO).

Now, let’s commit transaction in session 1

Now lets say you commit the transaction, in session 2, now you'll get the new updated value:

```
COMMIT
SELECT *
FROM   DemoTable
WHERE i = 2
```

You can read more about it on Pinal Dave's blog: [blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/07/03/sql-server-difference-between-read-committed-snapshot-and-snapshot-isolation-level/](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/07/03/sql-server-difference-between-read-committed-snapshot-and-snapshot-isolation-level/)

Comment: His question is about RCSI, not about SNAPSHOT